Maven Test runs indefinitely on a Test Suite which executes fine in Junit4
I recently mavenized few old projects. When I am trying to build caffeine tests project with maven build, the test suite hangs when it executes the first test.
I debugged the application, it adds all the tests in the test suite but when it tries to execute the first test, it hangs and the stack frame disappears. But the remote java application doesn't crash, it just waits forever.
But all the tests runs perfectly when running in Junit4.
It hangs exactly at this Stack Frame
Stack frame hangs at CaffeineLauncher(TestCase).runBare()
Stack Frame gets erased after this
Stack Frame gets erased after this
Remote Java Application Debugging.
C:\Users\***\Caffeine Tests\src\main\resources>mvnDebug -DforkCount=0 test
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< caffeine-tests:caffeine-tests >--------------------
[INFO] Building caffeine-tests 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ caffeine-tests ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\***\Caffeine Tests\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.13.0:compile (default-compile) @ caffeine-tests ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ caffeine-tests ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\***\Caffeine Tests\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.13.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ caffeine-tests ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- surefire:3.3.0:test (default-test) @ caffeine-tests ---
[WARNING] useSystemClassLoader setting has no effect when not forking
[WARNING] The parameter forkCount should likely not be 0. Forking a JVM for tests improves test accuracy. Ensure to have a <forkCount> >= 1.
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider
[INFO] Running caffeine.test.TestCaffeine

Test Caffeine
package caffeine.test;

import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

public final class TestCaffeine extends junit.framework.TestSuite {
    public TestCaffeine() {
        super();
    }
    public TestCaffeine(final Class theClass) {
        super(theClass);
    }
    public TestCaffeine(final String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    public static Test suite() {
        final TestCaffeine suite = new TestCaffeine();

            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.aggregation3.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite
                .addTest(new TestSuite(caffeine.test.array.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.association1.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.association2.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.collection.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.composition1.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.composition2.CaffeineLauncher.class));
        suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
            caffeine.test.composition3.CaffeineLauncher.class));
        suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
            caffeine.test.composition4.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.composition5.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.composition6.counterexample.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.composition7.counterexample.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.composition8.counterexample.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.composition9.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.interactiondiagram1.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.interactiondiagram2.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.multithreading1.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.multithreading2.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.nextEvent2.CaffeineLauncher.class));
            suite.addTest(new TestSuite(
                caffeine.test.nextEvent3.CaffeineLauncher.class));

        return suite;
    }
}

pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>net.ptidej</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-ptidej</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>caffeine-tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine-tests</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>21</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.ptidej.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>

I cleaned all the projects, updated maven projects but no Idea why it could possibly get stuck.

You should use mvn instead of mvnDebug because mvnDebug starts a debugging session to debug Maven itself and waits on the connection from your IDE.... Another quesiton is comming into my mind. Why do you use JUnit 4 instead of JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5) ... and more interesting why do you use TestSuite instead of using naming conventions and run the tests...

If you like to debug your test you can execute a test directly via your IDE...

Actually, I can't change from Junit 4 and since it's an old project TestSuite was used.  I initially tried with mvn clean verify install, but it's same result as above. So I used mvnDebug to check what's the issue and this was the case.
But all the tests in the TestSuite execute perfectly in Junit4.

Just use mvn clean verify instead of mvn clean verify install

I have used mvn clean verify too, but still the same result : /
